# changing UITableViewCell background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know this might have been asked thousands time, I tried changing the background for my UITablewViewCell via the following:

```
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
              cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
```

and all I have now is:

[image]

How do I set that accessory view background view color as well?

**UPDATE:**
I have a section header on top in which it has a white background

Answer (score 13):

Put this in your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: does this changes the section as well?

Comment: It shouldn't change the section colour, you'd have to do that yourself by implementing `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and returning your own view.

Comment: this is the only solution out of many that worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating it a bit.  You can just change the tableview's background color which does exactly what you want.  This way, you don't have to set the color for EVERY cell. :)

```
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: I actually have a section on top, in which I don't want to have a blue background.. should have shown that in the screenshot

Comment: Can you add the screenshot to your post?
Are you talking about the table view header view?

Answer (score -3):

```
//in willDisplayCell
if (indexPath.section > 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```